# Is every Grothendieck category with a generator a category of sheaves?

Tags: ct.category-theory, topos-theory, abelian-categories

The [Gabriel-Popescu theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gabriel%E2%80%93Popescu_theorem) tells us that every Grothendieck category with a generator is a left exact localization of a module category. I'm interested in a slightly different way of "representing" such categories:

**Question:** Let $\mathcal C$ be a Grothendieck category with a generator.

1. Does there exist a Grothendieck topos $\mathcal X$ such that $\mathcal C \simeq Ab(\mathcal X)$ is equivalent to the category of abelian group objects in $\mathcal X$?
2. Slightly less naively, does there exist a ringed Grothendieck topos $(\mathcal X, \mathcal O_{\mathcal X})$ such that $\mathcal C \simeq \mathcal O_{\mathcal X}\textrm{-}Mod$ is equivalent to the category of $\mathcal O_\mathcal X$-modules?
3. Same as (2), but with $(\mathcal X, \mathcal O_{\mathcal X})$ being locally ringed?

Comment: You actually also get from Gabriel-Popescu that every Grothendieck category is a left exact accessible localisation of presheaves of abelian groups. This should solve 1.

Comment: @user40276 I don't think I follow. I can see how the Gabriel-Popescu theorem exhibits a Grothendieck category as a localization of a category of $Ab$-enriched presheaves on a certain $Ab$-enriched caetgory (viz. a certain ring) -- but I want to relate this to a topos -- i.e. a category of sheaves of sets on a certain $Set$-enriched category.

Comment: It seems that the smallest Grothendieck topology generated by the "additive Grothendieck topology" of presheaves of abelian groups on that pre-additive category should work. But, now, that I think again about it, I'm not so sure...

Comment: Isn't it true that, given a topos $\mathcal{G}$, its category of internal abelian groups $\mathsf{Ab}(\mathcal{G})$ is equivalent to a category of sheaves of abelian groups? This remark might be a building block to answer positively to the first question.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the answer is no, but I don't know a proof off the top of my head.  In noncommutative algebraic geometry, they take Grothendieck categories of graded modules over a graded ring, modulo finite-dimensional modules.  If there was a result like you have in mind, the theory would probably be very different.

Comment: Oh yeah -- Question 1 is probably ruled out because a category $Ab(\mathcal X)$ has a nice symmetric monoidal structure, which probably doesn't exist on most Grothendieck categories. And Question 3 probably doesn't make much sense when you realize that $\mathcal O_{\mathcal X}$ will have to be noncommutative!

Comment: In fact, Hovey [shows](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jpaa.2010.06.024) (Thm 3.3) that if $R$ is a division ring which is not a field, then the category $RMod$ of left $R$-modules does not admit any additive closed symmetric monoidal structure. This is a counterexample to (1) and to (2,3) unless we allow $\mathcal O_{\mathcal X}$ to be noncommutative. If we assume our Grothendieck category is symmetric monoidal closed, I'd still be interested to see if maybe it must be of the form $\mathcal O_{\mathcal X}Mod$ with $\mathcal O_{\mathcal X}$ commutative.

Comment: @TimCampion Hmm... so I was just rereading Caramello's arXiv preprint [Motivic Toposes](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1507.06271.pdf) and in the bottom half of p. 10, she says that any abelian category is equiv. to a full subcategory of the category of abelian objects in the topos of regular sheaves on a specific syntactic site, which suggests Question 1 can be saved after a slight modification. Taking Caramello's result on face value and linking this with Hovey's result, perhaps problems emerge in that the associated full subcategory need not be a monoidal?