# Is the category of quasi-coherent sheaves not a topos?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ct.category-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, topos-theory

There are two parts to my question:

**Question #1:** First a sanity-check: Am I right in that the category of quasi-coherent sheaves (over e.g. an affine scheme) is not a topos?

My reasoning is thus:

It is well-known that there is no non-trivial category that is both a topos and an abelian category -- since the topos is cartesian closed, it cannot have a 0 object without becoming trivial (see here: [Can a topos ever be an abelian category?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/10290/can-a-topos-ever-be-an-abelian-category)).

However, by the affine Serre theorem, it is well-known that the category of $R$-modules is equivalent to $QCoh(Spec(R))$, or the category of quasi-coherent sheaves on the space $Spec(R)$. Since the category of $R$-modules is abelian, it follows that the category $QCoh(Spec(R))$ is not a topos despite the fact that it is some kind of category of sheaves (satisfying some extra property). Am I correct?

**Question #2)** If this is true, can someone give me a conceptual understanding of why one would wish to present the category of $R$-modules as the category of quasi-coherent sheaves, even if it's not a topos?

I get the rough idea that we're constructing the category of $R$-modules from the categories of modules over local rings $R_{\mathfrak{p}}$ -- but I'm not sure I understand this very clearly. Can someone explain this a bit more clearly? Where does quasi-coherence figure in this picture?

Further, suppose we have a category of sheaves over the site $Spec(R)$ endowed with the Zariski topology, which is a topos (right?). Is the internal category of $R$-modules within this topos equivalent to the category of quasi-coherent sheaves? Or is that not the right way to think about the category of quasi-coherent sheaves? (Perhaps the answer is sitting in Ingo's PhD thesis somewhere, but I haven't found it...)

Comment: One simple reason to represent $R$-modules as some kind of sheaves over $\operatorname{Spec}R$ is that you want to find a definition that works also for non-affine schemes...

Comment: If you study algebraic geometry, you will for one reason or another probably be interested in sheaves on your spaces anyway. Quasicoherent sheaves are those which, at least locally, behave well under localization. Alternatively there is the (classical) description as sheaves which locally admit presentations. These categories end up being equivalent to categories of modules, and generalize nicely to other schemes, despite the fact they aren't topoi.

Comment: As a matter of fact $\mathrm{Qco}(X)$ is a Grothendieck category, i.e. an abelian category with a set of generators and that satisfies AB5, directed colimits are exact. These categories may be considered as the additive analogous of a topos (as the category of abelian objects in a topos with enough points is).

Comment: Toposes are categories of sheaves _of sets_. As Leo Alonso says, the abelian analogue of a topos is a Grothendieck abelian category.

Comment: @ZhenLin Out of curiosity: abelian categories are Barr exact categories - in particular, they can interpret regular logic. It is also well-known that sheaf toposes may also be regarded as classifying toposes of a geometry theory (in fact many), and contains the generic model of the theory. I am told that this is related to 'forcing' in set theory, and has to do with the sheafiness of the topos (though perhaps I've misunderstood). Since the category of quasi-coherent sheaves (of modules) are also sheafy, is there an analogous generic model living inside it for some regular theory?

Comment: If you have a regular theory then there is a small regular category – the so-called syntactic category – that contains a universal model; the classifying topos is the Grothendieck topos "completion" of that. Not every Grothendieck topos arises in this way. "Sheafiness" is irrelevant, in my view – it is just an "implementation detail". One can ask about, for example, the Grothendieck abelian category "completion" of a small regular category. It is not obvious to me whether this is necessarily some kind of category of sheaves of abelian groups on a site – and I think it is not.

Comment: To amplify: the only abelian category which is a topos is the zero category. In fact, the only additive category which is a topos is the zero category. In fact, the only category with a zero object which is a topos is the zero category. In a topos which is not the zero category, there is no morphism $1 \to \emptyset$ where $1$ is the terminal object and $\emptyset$ is the initial object. Whereas in a category with zero object, these two objects are isomorphic.

Comment: I believe that the other comments already resolved most of your questions, right? If not, please indicate where you'd appreciate additional detail. Regarding your question on internal categories: The external category of all sheaves of $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules (not only the quasicoherent ones) is internally the category of all $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules (where now $\mathcal{O}_X$ is a plain old ring, not a sheaf). The external category of quasicoherent $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules is internally a certain subcategory of that category (the condition for a module to be quasicoherent ...

Comment: ... can be phrased in the internal language, that is Theorem 8.3 in [my thesis](https://rawgit.com/iblech/internal-methods/master/notes.pdf)). In the case $X = \mathrm{Spec}(R)$, you could internally to the topos $\mathrm{Sh}(X)$ consider the constant sheaf $\underline{R}$, but modules over it are not particularly interesting. The structure sheaf $\mathcal{O}_X$ is not $\underline{R}$, but a certain localization of $\underline{R}$ (the localization at the "generic prime filter" -- a filter which does not exist in $\mathrm{Set}$, but does exist in $\mathrm{Sh}(X)$).

Comment: @ZhenLin Hmm… IIRC every Groth. topos is a classifying topos of a geometric theory, and for every geom. theory, one can construct the syntactic site and the category of sheaves on it — yielding a classifying topos. In this way, can’t every Groth. topos be regarded as arising from a completion of a syntactic category? Also, you don’t have to give me the full details, but is there an intuition abt why you’re skeptical that the Groth. abel. category completion of a regular category isn’t some kind of category of sheaves of abel. groups? Nw if not, but just curious if you had an example in mind.

Comment: @IngoBlechschmidt Hey there - yes, I got some good info, but also just to make sure I’ve got things right:

a) The category of sheaves of $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules over $X$ can be viewed as a topos Sh$(X)$ with $\mathcal{O}_X$ as the internal ring object, right? Your thesis mentions how quasi-coherent modules look like internally, but how exactly does that definition force $\mathcal{O}_X$ to be a localisation of $R$ at some generic prime filter of $R$? Could you say more about this? (If it helps, I'm acquainted w/ Johnstone's paper on Rings, Fields, Spectra).

Comment: b) Going off of what ZhenLin said, the generic prime filter doesn’t just exist in Sh$(X)$, but also exists in the syntactic category - what is the difference between the generic model in these two environments? e.g. Do all of your internal characterisations of external properties work only for sheafy toposes, or can they be extended naturally to the setting of syntactic categories? What are the advantages of working in one setting vs. the other?

Comment: Also, haven't had the chance to thank everyone in this thread, but thanks for either providing helpful sanity checks or giving useful nuggets of info that I wasn't aware of before. As you probably can tell, I'm not too familiar w/ algebraic geometry and am starting to educate myself on this, so am still trying to get my bearings, and the small comments do help in getting rid of unnecessary confusion/uncertainty, which is very much welcome.

Comment: @asldjk The Gabriel–Popescu theorem says that every Grothendieck abelian category can be embedded in a category of modules by a functor with an exact left adjoint. More generally any full subcategory of the category of additive functors $\mathcal{C}^\textrm{op} \to \textbf{Ab}$ whose inclusion has an exact left adjoint is a Grothendieck abelian category. So far so good, in terms of the analogy with Grothendieck toposes. But now you have to give an "elementary" description of such full subcategories in terms of $\mathcal{C}$ à la Grothendieck topologies. I don't think this is possible.

Comment: @ZhenLin Ahh I found [this question by Tim Campion](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/333955/is-every-grothendieck-category-with-a-generator-a-category-of-sheaves), which gives an example of a Grothendieck category not being equivalent to a category of sheaves. Hmm... interesting. I'm warming up to the idea now that sheafiness is indeed somewhat irrelevant. So much for my understanding of generic models being the result of sheaf-theoretic forcing since they cannot be Set-based models.